# java.lang.runtimeexception unable to instantiate receiver

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an appliacation that scans the beacon.
when application scans the beacon, application will change the UI Text that received the BR(BroadcastReceiver) message.

After app  starts, If Button is clicked, service is started.
and If beacon is scanned, activity class received BR message from service class and Ui Text is changed. 
but a one or two second later app is closed with error log.

---

**CODE : 
MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button start;
TextView text;
private final String SERVER_ADDRESS = "";
Handler handler;
BeaconReceiver receiver;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
    text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
    receiver = new BeaconReceiver();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("com.example.beaconTEST.TEST");
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    phpconnect();
    start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent;
            intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BeaconService.class);
            startService(intent);
        }
    });
}
private class BeaconReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.i("receive", "success");
            String result = intent.getStringExtra("result");
            text.setText(result);
    }

}

public void phpconnect(){
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            try{                        
                URL url = new URL(SERVER_ADDRESS + "/Beacon_Infor.php?");
                Log.i("url","url : "+url);
                url.openStream();
                Log.i("stream","success");
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("Error", "Error : " + e.getMessage());
            }   

        }       
    });

}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Intent intent;
    intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BeaconService.class);
    stopService(intent);
}
```

}

**CODE : BeaconService.java**

```
public class BeaconService extends Service {
CentralManager centralManager;
Handler handler;
Thread t;   
String result;
int count=0;
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
    setCentralManager();
    handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    t = new Thread(new Runnable() { 
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    centralManager.startScanning();
                }
            });
        }
    });
    Log.i("Service", "Start");
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Start", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    XmlParser xmlGetter = new XmlParser();
    result = xmlGetter.getXmlData("result.xml", "uuid");
    Log.i("Beacon", "name : " + result );
}
public void onDestroy(){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service End", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if(centralManager.isScanning()) {
        centralManager.stopScanning();
    }
    centralManager.close();
    super.onDestroy();
}
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
    Log.i("onStartCommand", "Start");
    t.start();
    return START_STICKY;
}

public void setCentralManager() {
    centralManager = CentralManager.getInstance();
    centralManager.init(getApplicationContext());
    centralManager.setPeripheralScanListener(new PeripheralScanListener() {         
        @Override
        public void onPeripheralScan(Central central, final Peripheral peripheral) {
            if(result.equals(peripheral.getProximityUUID()))
            {
                Log.i("count","count : "+ count);
                if(count ==0)
                {
                Log.i("uuid", "result : "+result);
                Intent resultIntent = new Intent("com.example.beaconTEST.TEST");
                resultIntent.putExtra("result", result);
                //sendBroadcast(resultIntent);
                count++;
                }


            }
        }           
    });
}
```

}

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<receiver android:exported="false" android:name="com.example.beaconTest.BeaconReceiver">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="com.example.beaconTEST.TEST"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name="com.example.becaontest.BeaconService">
    </service>
```

**LOG**

```
enter code here03-30 20:25:22.088: I/ViewRootImpl(22750): ViewRoot's Touch   
               Event : Touch Down
               03-30 20:25:22.148: I/ViewRootImpl(22750): ViewRoot's Touch Event : Touch UP
               03-30 20:25:22.178: I/Service(22750): Start
               03-30 20:25:22.218: I/Beacon(22750): name : d5756247-57a2-4344-915d-9599497940a7
               03-30 20:25:22.218: I/onStartCommand(22750): Start
               03-30 20:25:22.258: D/BluetoothAdapter(22750): stopLeScan()
               03-30 20:25:22.258: D/BluetoothAdapter(22750): startLeScan(): null
               03-30 20:25:22.258: D/BluetoothAdapter(22750): onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=6
               03-30 20:25:23.268: D/BluetoothAdapter(22750): onScanResult() - Device=D0:39:72:A4:96:95 RSSI=-88
               03-30 20:25:23.278: I/count(22750): count : 0
               03-30 20:25:23.278: I/uuid(22750): result : d5756247-57a2-4344-915d-9599497940a7
               03-30 20:25:23.278: I/receive(22750): success
               03-30 20:25:23.278: I/result(22750): result : d5756247-57a2-4344-915d-9599497940a7
               03-30 20:25:24.228: D/BluetoothAdapter(22750): onScanResult() - Device=D0:39:72:A4:96:95 RSSI=-62
               03-30 20:25:24.238: I/count(22750): count : 1
               03-30 20:25:25.228: D/BluetoothAdapter(22750): onScanResult() - Device=D0:39:72:A4:96:95 RSSI=-53
               03-30 20:25:25.238: I/count(22750): count : 1
               03-30 20:25:26.238: D/BluetoothAdapter(22750): onScanResult() - Device=D0:39:72:A4:96:95 RSSI=-53
               03-30 20:25:26.248: I/count(22750): count : 1
               03-30 20:25:27.248: D/BluetoothAdapter(22750): onScanResult() - Device=D0:39:72:A4:96:95 RSSI=-63
               03-30 20:25:27.248: I/count(22750): count : 1
               03-30 20:25:28.248: D/BluetoothAdapter(22750): onScanResult() - Device=D0:39:72:A4:96:95 RSSI=-63
               03-30 20:25:28.268: I/count(22750): count : 1
               03-30 20:25:28.268: D/AndroidRuntime(22750): Shutting down VM
               03-30 20:25:28.268: W/dalvikvm(22750): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4188de48)
               03-30 20:25:28.278: E/AndroidRuntime(22750): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
               03-30 20:25:28.278: E/AndroidRuntime(22750): Process: com.example.becaontest, PID: 22750
               03-30 20:25:28.278: E/AndroidRuntime(22750): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.example.beaconTest.BeaconReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.beaconTest.BeaconReceiver" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.becaontest-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.becaontest-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
               03-30 20:25:28.278: E/AndroidRuntime(22750):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2408)
               03-30 20:25:28.278: E/AndroidRuntime(22750):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:142)
               03-30 20:25:28.278: E/AndroidRuntime(22750):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1279)
               03-30 20:25:28.278: E/AndroidRuntime(22750):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
               03-30 20:25:28.278: E/AndroidRuntime(22750):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
               03-30 20:25:28.278: E/AndroidRuntime(22750):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5120)
               03-30 20:25:28.278: E/AndroidRuntime(22750):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
               03-30 20:25:28.278: E/AndroidRuntime(22750):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
               03-30 20:25:28.278: E/AndroidRuntime(22750):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
               03-30 20:25:28.278: E/AndroidRuntime(22750):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
               03-30 20:25:28.278: E/AndroidRuntime(22750):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
               03-30 20:25:28.278: E/AndroidRuntime(22750): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.beaconTest.BeaconReceiver" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.becaontest-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.becaontest-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
               03-30 20:25:28.278: E/AndroidRuntime(22750):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
               03-30 20:25:28.278: E/AndroidRuntime(22750):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
               03-30 20:25:28.278: E/AndroidRuntime(22750):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
               03-30 20:25:28.278: E/AndroidRuntime(22750):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2403)
               03-30 20:25:28.278: E/AndroidRuntime(22750):     ... 10 more
               03-30 20:25:29.258: D/BluetoothAdapter(22750): onScanResult() - Device=D0:39:72:A4:96:95 RSSI=-65
               03-30 20:25:29.268: I/count(22750): count : 1
               03-30 20:25:30.278: D/BluetoothAdapter(22750): onScanResult() - Device=D0:39:72:A4:96:95 RSSI=-66
               03-30 20:25:30.278: I/count(22750): count : 1
               03-30 20:25:32.288: D/BluetoothAdapter(22750): onScanResult() - Device=D0:39:72:A4:96:95 RSSI=-58
               03-30 20:25:32.298: I/count(22750): count : 1
               03-30 20:25:33.298: D/BluetoothAdapter(22750): onScanResult() - Device=D0:39:72:A4:96:95 RSSI=-57
               03-30 20:25:33.308: I/count(22750): count : 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your code and error, you do not appear to have a `com.example.beaconTest.BeaconReceiver` class. The `BeaconReceiver` that you declare in your Java code is a private inner class of `MainActivity`, and therefore Android cannot create an instance of it. You would need to use `registerReceiver()`, instead of the manifest, to register your `BeaconReceiver`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I already used registerReceiver() on onCreat(), MainActivity. you will be able to find source code.

Comment: @Park: That does not matter. You are crashing because of the incorrect manifest entry. Fix your manifest, such as by removing the `<receiver>` element (you do not need one for receivers registered via `registerReceiver()`).

Comment: Thank you. I fixed manifest and there is no error in the app.

Answer (score 0):

- i donot see where the receiver is initialized. the code is commented out `//receiver = new BeaconReceiver();`
- you register the receiver in onCreate but you donot unregister it in on destroy. if your activity closes, its receiver still may receive data and tries to update the gui, that is not valid anymore. This will crash your app.
- since you are (un-)registering your receiver yourself, remove it from the manifest.

Comment: Thank for your comment. "//receiver = new BeacoReceiver." code is my mistake. original souce code except the '//' code. I'll input unregister code in onDestroy().

Answer (score 0):

In your Android Manifest file you have declared com.example.beaconTest.BeaconReceiver inside com.example.beaconTest package but actual location of  BeaconReceiver  is com.example.beaconTest.MainActivity$BeaconReceiver because BeaconReceiver is a inner class.i.e you are getting this error.